# Javascript browser visibility when child iframe is not in focus

Tags: javascript, iframe, zendesk, zendesk-app

Here is what I am trying to achieve:

- We are using Zendesk for Customer Service.
- Zendesk offers the possibility to add private apps to the support interface.
- We are trying to identify when we are actually working on tickets pricely being in the ticket interface answering or filling information.

[image]

The private App is the only thing where we can control the Iframe / Javascript.

Things we already can see:

- If we switch browser Tab from Tab A to Tab B (Event: Inactive)
- If we switch back to Tab A (Event: Active)

The problem:

- When clicking on the Zendesk part of the screen My App loses focus according to the events we see.
- Clicking back on the App part returns the focus.
- When we ALT + Tab away from the browser (e.g. into another App) there is no event triggered, UNLESS: the Iframe is clicked on before.

Here is the code that is used for the App:

```
var hidden, visibilityChange;
var visability;
var client;

if (typeof document.hidden !== "undefined") {
  hidden = "hidden";
  visibilityChange = "visibilitychange";
} else if (typeof document.mozHidden !== "undefined") {
  hidden = "mozHidden";
  visibilityChange = "mozvisibilitychange";
} else if (typeof document.msHidden !== "undefined") {
  hidden = "msHidden";
  visibilityChange = "msvisibilitychange";
} else if (typeof document.webkitHidden !== "undefined") {
  hidden = "webkitHidden";
  visibilityChange = "webkitvisibilitychange";
}

var supported = !(
  typeof document.addEventListener === "undefined" || hidden === undefined
);

if (supported) {
    document.addEventListener(visibilityChange, onVisibilityChange, false);
}

function isTabVisible() {
  return supported && !document[hidden];
}

// === tailor to your needs === //
function onVisibilityChange(){
    visability = isTabVisible();
    console.log('[Visibility] Tab visibility changed. Visible ?', isTabVisible());
    main(client);
    // add Main here?!
}



document.onfocus = function() {
    console.log('App is on focus');
};

document.onblur = function() {
    console.log('App is blurred');
};

$(function() {
    client = ZAFClient.init();
    client.invoke('resize', {width: '100%', height: '375px'});
    main(client);
});



async function main(client) {
    visability = isTabVisible();
    console.log("[Visibility] Visible in Main?", isTabVisible());
};
```

The part of Blur and Focus is the one that I read multiple times will do the trick for us which is true but only if "My App" part was clicked on before

```
document.onfocus = function() {
    console.log('App is on focus');
};

document.onblur = function() {
    console.log('App is blurred');
};
```

Is there any way to get the wanted behavior which is:
Keeping Focus or triggering the blur event as long we are on the browser window no matter if its the app or somewhere else?

EDIT:
Tried out the following code:

```
    window.top.onfocus = function() {
    console.log('Top is on focus');
      };

    window.top.onblur = function() {
        console.log('Top is blurred');
    };
```

This gives me the error message:

> Uncaught DOMException: Permission denied to access property "onfocus" on cross-origin object

Comment: Should you not rather listen to the [`blur`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/blur_event) event on the top window, if you want it in any case? If the document is not focused it is not going to trigger blur on tabbing out.

Comment: @Lain Changing the ```document.onblur``` -> ```window.onblur``` doesnt do anything.